# syntax error identifier 'FilterHandle' minifilter

Tags: c++, minifilter

I learning how to develop mini filter driver through youtube tutorials: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9rErMsfmK_U&list=PLZ4EgN7ZCzJyUT-FmgHsW4e9BxfP-VMuo&index=12

I almost copy pasted as it is in the tutorial, I am getting a ton more errors than him:

My Code:

```
#include <fltKernel.h>
#include <dontuse.h>
#include <suppress.h>
#include "precomp.h"

PFLT_FILTER FilterHandle = NULL;
NTSTATUS MiniUnload (FLT_FILTER_UNLOAD_FLAGS Flags);
FLT_POSTOP_CALLBACK_STATUS MiniPostCreate(PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data, PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects, PVOID* CompletionContext, FLT_POST_OPERATION_FLAGS flags);
FLT_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS MiniPreCreate(PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data, PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects, PVOID* CompletionContext);
FLT_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS MiniPreWrite(PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data, PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects, PVOID* CompletionContext);


const FLT_OPERATION_REGISTRATION Callbacks[] = {
    {IRP_MJ_CREATE,0,MiniPreCreate,MiniPostCreate},
    {IRP_MJ_WRITE,0,MiniPreCreate,NULL},
    {IRP_MJ_OPERATION_END}
};
const FLT_REGISTRATION FilterRegistration = {
    sizeof(FLT_REGISTRATION),
    FLT_REGISTRATION_VERSION,
    0,
    NULL,
    Callbacks,
    MiniUnload,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL
};
NTSTATUS MiniUnload(FLT_FILTER_UNLOAD_FLAGS Flags) {
    KdPrint(("driver unload \r\n"));
    FltUnregisterFilter(FilterHandle);
    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
FLT_POSTOP_CALLBACK_STATUS MiniPostCreate(PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data, PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects,PVOID* CompletionContext,FLT_POST_OPERATION_FLAGS flags) {
    KdPrint(("Post Create is running \r\n"));
    return FLT_POSTOP_FINISHED_PROCESSING;
}
FLT_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS MiniPreCreate(PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data, PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects,PVOID* CompletionContext) {
    PFLT_FILE_NAME_INFORMATION FileNameInfo;
    NTSTATUS status;
    WCHAR Name[300] = {0};

    status = FltGetFileNameInformation(Data, FLT_FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED|FLT_FILE_NAME_QUERY_DEFAULT,&FileNameInfo);
    if (NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        status = FltParseFileNameInformation(FileNameInfo);
        if (NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
            if (FileNameInfo->Name.MaximumLength < 260) {
                RtlCopyMemory(Name, FileNameInfo->Name.Buffer, FileNameInfo->Name.MaximumLength);
                KdPrint(("CreateFile: %ws \r\n", Name));
            }
        }
        FltReleaseFileNameInformation(FileNameInfo);
    }

    return FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_WITH_CALLBACK;
}

FLT_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS MiniPreWrite(PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data, PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects, PVOID* CompletionContext) {
    PFLT_FILE_NAME_INFORMATION FileNameInfo;
    NTSTATUS status;
    WCHAR Name[300] = { 0 };

    status = FltGetFileNameInformation(Data, FLT_FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED | FLT_FILE_NAME_QUERY_DEFAULT, &FileNameInfo);
    if (NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        status = FltParseFileNameInformation(FileNameInfo);
        if (NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
            if (FileNameInfo->Name.MaximumLength < 260) {
                RtlCopyMemory(Name, FileNameInfo->Name.Buffer, FileNameInfo->Name.MaximumLength);
                _wcsupr(Name);
                if (wcsstr(Name, L"OPENME.TXT") != NULL) {
                    KdPrint(("Write File: %ws Blocked \r\n", Name));
                    Data->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER;
                    Data->IoStatus.Information = 0;
                    FltReleaseFileNameInformation(FileNameInfo);
                    return FLT_PREOP_COMPLETE;
                }
                KdPrint(("CreateFile: %ws \r\n", Name));
            }
        }
        FltReleaseFileNameInformation(FileNameInfo);
    }

    return FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_WITH_CALLBACK;
}


NTSTATUS DriverEntry(PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath) {
    NTSTATUS status;

    status = FltRegisterFilter(DriverObject, &FilterRegistration, &FilterHandle);
    if (NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        status = FltStartFiltering(FilterHandle);
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
            FltUnregisterFilter(FilterHandle);
        }
    }
    return status;
}
```

I am getting these errors:

```
c2061   syntax error: identifier 'FilterHandle' error  Line 6
syntax error: ';' Line 6
'': no variable declared before '=' Line 6
...
```

My project type is: Filter Driver: NDIS.

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here? I don't understand why `PFLT_FILTER FilterHandle = NULL;` have all of these issues.

Comment: Look at the warnings as well.  precomp.h must be first.

Comment: @HansPassant Now I am getting `'perprocess': redifinition, different basic types` and `'PETHREAD': redifinition; different basic types` error

Comment: The redifinition is because you probably have ntifs after ntddk, which is going to be problematic. I highly recommend centralizing kernel headers in one and then including that.

Comment: @LeberechtReinhold I did that as well, I moved all the headers to `"precomp.h"` and then `#include "precomh.h"`. Now I get dozen of errors complaing about `PFLT_FILTER` is undefined and etc.